# testRegistrar is failing with error (ReferenceError: 'testRegistrar' is not defined at :1:1)

Tags: swarm, ens

I am trying to host my own website of Swarm. But I am getting the following error (the last line in bold) when trying to register:

> >eth.accounts
>
> ["0x090c84e3ae32dcd38be0525223e87ac3393a763e"]
>
> >web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
>
> 1
>
> >loadScript('/home/hadoopcd/ensutils.js')
>
> true
>
> >personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
>
> Unlock account 0x090c84e3ae32dcd38be0525223e87ac3393a763e
>
> >testRegistrar.register(web3.sha3('argo'), eth.accounts[0],{from: eth.accounts[0]})
>
> **ReferenceError: 'testRegistrar' is not defined
>       at :1:1**

I downloaded the ensutils.js from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/ens/master/ensutils.js'.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the testnet version util file at here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/ens/master/ensutils-ropsten.js

The one you're using is for the mainnet which doesn't provide `TestRegistrar`.

And please be aware of which network is active. Hope this helps.